# Aggregate elements of a list containing relativedelta objects

Tags: python, list, relativedelta

I have a list **myList** that contains **relativedelta objects**. I want to add all of these relativedeltas objects.
I tried:

```
sum(myList)
```

but it gives TypeError.

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'relativedelta'
```

Even though relativedelta objects can be added with + Opeartor

Code somehow:

```
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

date1 = datetime(2018, 4, 9).date()
date2 = datetime(2019, 8, 18).date()
date3 = datetime(2014, 2, 1).date()
date4 = datetime(2018, 12, 30).date()

myList = []

rdelta1 = relativedelta(date2, date1)
myList.append(rdelta1)


rdelta2 = relativedelta(date4, date3)
myList.append(rdelta2)

print(sum(myList))
```

Comment: There seems to be an integer in your list of relativedeltas, without a reproducible example is all we can say

Comment: You should provide a minimal reproducible example (i.e. a small list reproducing the issue)

Comment: You should try `functools.reduce()` instead

Comment: I added code to question.

Comment: @mozway code is added.

Comment: @ScootCork there is no integer in code. I updated the question. see the code section to reproduce.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use reduce

```
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
from functools import reduce

date1 = datetime(2018, 4, 9).date()
date2 = datetime(2019, 8, 18).date()
date3 = datetime(2014, 2, 1).date()
date4 = datetime(2018, 12, 30).date()

myList = []

rdelta1 = relativedelta(date2, date1)
myList.append(rdelta1)


rdelta2 = relativedelta(date4, date3)
myList.append(rdelta2)

print(reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, myList))
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because [*`sum`* uses start value as `0`.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum)

```
>>> help(sum)
Help on built-in function sum in module builtins:

sum(iterable, /, start=0)
    Return the sum of a 'start' value (default: 0) plus an iterable of numbers

    When the iterable is empty, return the start value.
    This function is intended specifically for use with numeric values and may    reject non-numeric types.
```

For example, *`sum([1, 2])`* is `0 + 1 + 2`

```
>>> sum([1, 2])
3
```

*`sum([1, 2], start=7)`* is `7 + 1 + 2`

```
>>> sum([1, 2], start=7)
10
```

So to solve this use one item(`relativedelta` object) as `start` argument and keep everything else in the iterable.

```
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

date1 = datetime(2018, 4, 9).date()
date2 = datetime(2019, 8, 18).date()
date3 = datetime(2014, 2, 1).date()
date4 = datetime(2018, 12, 30).date()

myList = []

rdelta1 = relativedelta(date2, date1)

rdelta2 = relativedelta(date4, date3)
myList.append(rdelta2)

print(sum(myList, rdelta1)) # so both start and items in `MyList` are `relativedelta` types.
```

Comment: Nicely spotted!

Comment: relativedate objects are added via a for loop and I don't want to use an extra variable for storing rdelta1. In your answer, I have to do something before for loop like date1 = dates[0] and then use the usual for loop.

Comment: @ShaidaMuhammad Agree!, My post explains why `sum` raises error when adding `relativedelta` objects(As stated in your question) and how to get rid of it(using `sum` itself), But that does not mean  it's the *pythonic* solution :).  I would also recommend to use the `reduce ` function.

Comment: @AbduNIyas Gotcha